# How do I get the log-in section to disappear when users are logged in?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the "log in block" to be hidden to my users once they are logged in.  It is very confusing to still see the log in section.  My users think that their log in didn't work when in actuality, they are successfully logged in.  I have tried inserting the following into my CSS block, but I need a condition to make it visible when users are NOT logged in.

```
display: none;
```

Here is my HTML code for this section:

```
    <DIV id="hp-content">
        <DIV id="hp-left-column">
            <DIV id="hp-sign-header">
            </DIV>
            <DIV id="hp-sign">
                <input type="textbox" class="ui-txt-general medium required" id="swsignin-txt-username" />
                <input type="password" class="ui-txt-general medium required" id="swsignin-txt-password" />
                <a title="Sign into my site." onclick="joelSignIn();" class="" id="swsignin-btn-submit"><img src="/cms/lib06/CA01000567/Centricity/Template/2/signin.png" alt="Sign In" /></a>
            </DIV>
```

Here is my CSS code for this section:

```
    #hp-sign-header{
        width: 288px;
        height: 27px;
        margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
        background: transparent url(/cms/lib06/CA01000567/Centricity/Template/2/sign-header.png) no-repeat scroll top center;
        }

    #hp-sign{
        width: 218px;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 35px;
        }

    #swsignin-txt-username, #swsignin-txt-password {
        border: 1px solid #0C304E;
        color: #6994B9;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 15px;
        height: 47px;
        margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 221px;
        }

    #swsignin-txt-username {
        background: transparent url(/cms/lib06/CA01000567/Centricity/Template/2/username.png) no-repeat scroll top left;
        }

    #swsignin-txt-password {
        background: transparent url(/cms/lib06/CA01000567/Centricity/Template/2/password.png) no-repeat scroll top left;
        }
```

Here is the JAVASCRIPT code for this section:

```
    function joelSignIn(){
    var data = "{Username: '" + addslashes($('#swsignin-txt-username').val()) + "',Password: '" + addslashes($('#swsignin-txt-password').val()) + "'} ";
    var success = "window.location.reload()";
    var failure = "if (result[0].reason === 'TOU') { DisplayTOU(); } else { CallControllerFailure(result[0].errormessage); }";
    var callPath = "../site/SiteController.aspx/SignIn";
    CallController(callPath, data, success, failure);
    }
```

So my question is, do I need to insert HTML code, CSS code and/or JAVASCRIPT code to make this work?  And what is the code that I need to insert and where?  I have tried researching and playing around, but to no avail.  Any advice would be MUCH appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: That would usually be done server side

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to coding.  What do you mean by "server side"?  Something that I have no access/control of?

Comment: if you are stuck entirely client-side, you could add a var that adds a class with display:none set to #hp-sign, that only fires after joelSignIn().

Comment: Hi albert,... what would that code look like exactly?

Comment: @albert won't that be triggered regardless of whether the login was successful?

Comment: @garry idk...hard to say without seeing it live, but if you look at CallController, its calling success which reloads the document. i could be wrong...but offhand makes sense to me

Comment: @catrina um... idk exactly without looking at the document. sorry. basically you need a var to getElementById hp-sign, then you'd want to attach a class of display:none to it. and then work that with an if statement, that will add the class to the element if login is successful.

Comment: It calls success but just reloads the page and, since apperently nothing is changing at the server-side, reloading the page will result in seeing exactly the same page as you had before logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't log in using javascript alone. Javascript is a [client-side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side) language, meaning it only operates on the user's computer. 'Logging in' suggests your visitors have something to log in *to*. That's usually a database running on the computer you're using to host your website, typically called the server. This can only be done at the [server-side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side).

Comment: So I can't hide the code that is shown on the website to log in? The section that has "user name", "password" and "sign in" are currently permanently on the homepage, regardless of if the user is signed in or not.

Comment: How does your page know they are signed in? What does the act of 'signing in' actually change?

Comment: Users have access to additional pages once they are logged in.  I work for a school so the classroom and parent information is only accessible if the parents are logged in.

Comment: Yes, but logged in to what? If it's a web application with authentication built-in, which it probably is, then you need to change the views people are presented with when they log in. You need to do this at the server-side. Javascript alone can't (or at any rate shouldn't) query your database.

Comment: OK,... I think I understand what you are saying.  I don't have access to the server-side. I only have access to the code that I posted above.

Comment: Then I stand by my original answer that it can't be done I'm afraid.

Comment: Bummer,... Thanks for your help, though, Garry!!